# Moving animation off screen with scroll view

Tags: animation, ios5, uiscrollview, xcode4.3

I have a small animation at the begining of my app, two doors open up horizontally, top and bottom to reveal screen.  All good so far, the top section moves off fine, however as i have a scroll view the page is longer than standard, 175000 to be exact.  Im usure of how to modify the code to send the bottom png off the screen as at the moment its stuck  going to where the standard screen would end.  Could someone advise? Ive tried so far manually adding the height after `self.view.size.height;` but that didn't work, im assuming its around there somewhere I should be altering

```
CGRect doortopFrame = doortop.frame;
doortopFrame.origin.y = -doortopFrame.size.height;

CGRect doorbottomFrame = doorbottom.frame;
doorbottomFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

doortop.frame = doortopFrame;
doorbottom.frame = doorbottomFrame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this,  changing bottom animation to `origin.X` does the trick